# zooming background images with CSS3

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have tried to make gentle zooming backgrounds like on this site http://iworks.ozythemes.com but with css3. I have tried transforming with scale on the body but then everything scales, which I don't want.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the `background-size` CSS3 property?

You can change the value of it with javascript.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I made it withe pure css3:

    body {

      background: url(../img/backPic.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
      -webkit-animation: warning 20s infinite ease-in;
  
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes warning {
     0% {
      background-size: 100%;
     }
     50% {
      background-size: 140%;
     }
     100% {
      background-size: 100%;
     }
    }

Because of the prefix -webkit- it only works in Chrome and Safari, but by implementing the other vendor prefixes also it will work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately currently have no method to zooming a background image using css,maybe you can try background-size:cover; to fit the background image.